# Active Rule Parameters table in SonarQube contains duplicates

Tags: oracle11g, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

We recently upgraded from SonarQube 5.1.2 to 5.2 then to 5.3 last week.

On Monday SonarQube crashed and wouldn't restart. Nothing in the log. Looking in the Oracle database, the `ACTIVE_RULE_PARAMETER` table showed *665k* duplicated parameters for a single custom `CheckStyle` rule (`Javadoc Method`) that was created after the upgrade.

Removing the duplicates allowed SonarQube to start.

Are there supposed to be constraints on the `ACTIVE_RULE_PARAMETER` table to avoid duplicates?  Creating other custom rules (`Whitespace Around` for example) has generated duplicates as well but none to the extent as we experienced Monday.